# Create a DIV that fills remainder of screen below variable height header

Tags: html, css

I have a header whose height may vary.
The footer has a fixed height.
The left hand and content must fill the screen height with the left nav taking fixed width and content taking remainder.

How do I do this?  Every solution I have seen so far that works has a fixed height for the header.

Just HTML and CSS please - no JS.

See: [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/BigMac66/y0rr8uf8/16/) (Code copied in full below)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <style type='text/css'>
    * {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
html, body{
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
p {
    line-height:1em;
}
ul {
    margin-left : 2em;
    list-style: none;
}
header {
    width: 100%;
    background-color:red;
    border-bottom-width: 0.25em;
    border-bottom-color: blue;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
}
nav {
    position:absolute;
    width: 15em;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:3.25em;
    background-color:gray;
    overflow:auto;
}
section {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:15em;
    bottom:3.25em;
    right:0;
    padding:0.25em;
    background-color:yellow;
    border-left-width: 0.25em;
    border-left-color: blue;
    border-left-style: solid;
    overflow:auto;
}
footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3.25em;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:green;
}
  </style>

</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <img src="http://www.luzchem.com/images/up1.jpg" style="vertical-align: top;" />
    <p>Menu and Search</p>
</header>
<div style="position:relative; height:100%;">
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Line 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Line 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Line 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<section>
    <p>Body</p>
</section>
<footer>
    <p>5509 Canotek RD, Unit 12, Ottawa Ontario, Canada, K1J9J9
        <br />Phone: (613) 749-2442 Fax: (613) 749-2393 Toll Free: (800) 397-0977
        <br /><a href="mailto:sales@luzchem.com?subject=General%20Inquiry&body=What%20do%20you%20want%20today%3F">sales@luzchem.com</a>
    </p>
<div style="position:relative; bottom:0;"> <span style="text-align:right; float:right; margin-right:1em;">Copyright &copy; 2012 Luzchem Research Inc.</span>
        <div style="text-align:left; float:left; margin-left:1em;"> <a href="company_info.php">Company Info</a>
 <a href="">Link_2</a>
 <a href="">Link_3</a>
        </div>
    </div>    
</footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution for you:
https://jsfiddle.net/3zgvrde8/

HTML:

```
 <header>
    <img src="http://www.luzchem.com/images/up1.jpg" style="vertical-align: top;" />
    <p>Menu and Search</p>
</header>
<div style="position:relative; display:block;height:100%">
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Line 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Line 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Line 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<section>
    <p>Body</p>
</section>
</div>
<footer>
    <p>5509 Canotek RD, Unit 12, Ottawa Ontario, Canada, K1J9J9
        <br />Phone: (613) 749-2442 Fax: (613) 749-2393 Toll Free: (800) 397-0977
        <br /><a href="mailto:sales@luzchem.com?subject=General%20Inquiry&body=What%20do%20you%20want%20today%3F">sales@luzchem.com</a>

    </p>
<div style="position:relative; bottom:0;"> <span style="text-align:right; float:right; margin-right:1em;">Copyright &copy; 2012 Luzchem Research Inc.</span>

        <div style="text-align:left; float:left; margin-left:1em;"> <a href="company_info.php">Company Info</a>
<a href="">Link_2</a>
 <a href="">Link_3</a>

        </div>
    </div>    
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
html, body{
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
p {
    line-height:1em;
}
ul {
    margin-left : 2em;
    list-style: none;
}
header {
    width: 100%;
    background-color:red;
    border-bottom-width: 0.25em;
    border-bottom-color: blue;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
}
nav {
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:3.25em;
    background-color:gray;
    float:left;
    width: 15em;
    display:block;
    height:100%
}
section {
    display:block;
    left:15em;
    padding:0.25em;
    background-color:yellow;
    border-left-width: 0.25em;
    border-left-color: blue;
    border-left-style: solid;
    overflow:auto;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%
}
footer {
    clear:both;
    bottom:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3.25em;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:green;
    position:absolute;
}
```

I would recommend separating your footer from your other content and positioning it so that it is absolutely positioned to the bottom.
Then with your left nav and content, float the nav with the fixed width so you can arrange your right content accordingly - no need to use absolute positioning here as they do not have fixed height nor positioning due to your variable header height.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes it does help - should have thought of it myself too!  Thanks a bunch!